# Add one more node in tree

Tags: nodes, tikz-trees

Question:

I have one MWE of tree in which i want to add one more node under G having lable I. How to do this?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [circle,draw]{F} [level distance=10mm,sibling distance=25mm]
    child { node [circle,draw]{D} [level distance=10mm ,sibling distance=15mm]
        child {node [circle,draw] {B}
            child {node [circle,draw] {A}}
            child {node [circle,draw]{C}}}
        child {node [circle,draw]{E}}
    }
    child {node [circle,draw] {J} [level distance=10mm ,sibling distance=15mm]
        child {node [circle,draw] {G}}
        child {node [circle,draw]{K}}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}    

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [circle,draw]{F} [level distance=10mm,sibling distance=25mm]
    child { node [circle,draw]{D} [level distance=10mm ,sibling distance=15mm]
        child {node [circle,draw] {B}
            child {node [circle,draw] {A}}
            child {node [circle,draw]{C}}}
        child {node [circle,draw]{E}}
    }
    child {node [circle,draw] {J} [level distance=10mm ,sibling distance=15mm]
        child {node [circle,draw] {G}
            child {node [circle, draw] {I}}  % <--- added node
                }
        child {node [circle,draw]{K}}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}    

\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
Solution based on your comment (if I understood you correctly):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [circle,draw]{F} [level distance=10mm,sibling distance=25mm]
    child { node [circle,draw]{D} [level distance=10mm ,sibling distance=15mm]
        child {node [circle,draw] {B}
            child {node [circle,draw] {A}}
            child {node [circle,draw]{C}}}
        child {node [circle,draw]{E}}
    }
    child {node [circle,draw] {J} [level distance=10mm ,sibling distance=15mm]
        child {node [circle,draw] {G}
            child[missing]                  % <--- added node
            child {node [circle, draw] {I}} % <--- added node
                }
        child {node [circle,draw]{K}}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternative solution with use of the `forest` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{forest}
for tree = {
    circle,
    draw,
    minimum size=1.5em,
    inner sep=2pt,
    s sep+=4mm
            }
[F
    [D
        [B
            [A]
            [C]
        ]
        [E]
    ]
    [J,fit=band
        [G
            [,phantom]
            [I]
        ]
        [K]
    ]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{center}
 \end{document}
```

which gives similar result:

[image]

Comment: yes but how to rotate node (I) to right

Comment: @Maths4Sandy, sorry, i do not understand you. What you like rotate? Text in node?

Comment: What you have added (node I)

Comment: @Maths4Sandy, yes, I added node I as you asked. Now you like to rotate node I. How you imagine this? Rotate text in node in the clockwise direction? To clarify what you mean, please provide a sketch (add it to your question).

Comment: In tree we can see that two nodes G and K are arranged below  node J slightly diagonal position. in same manner can we arrange our node I (with circle) in diagonal position

Comment: @Maths4Sandy, please see addendum to answer.

Comment: You understood me correctly. This is what I needed. Thanks millions times.